# What is the name of this strange white caterpillar?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

My friend found this caterpillar in south-central Tennessee in August. No identification guides or databases I've searched had a similar picture. Does anyone know the name of this species?

[image: white waxy/hairy insect larvae]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the size of this creature. The size can be an essential clue for identifications. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be sure without clearer pictures, but that looks like something in the genus *Eriocampa* and it could be a [Butternut Woollyworm (*Eriocampa juglandis*)](https://bugguide.net/node/view/32179).

Picture taken in Kentucky from BugGuide.net [© 2015 by dan40165](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd-nc/1.0/):
[image: Butternut Woollyworm (Eriocampa juglandis) from Bugguide.net]

These are the larvae of a sawfly (so not technically a caterpillar) and are about 1 inch long.

You can learn more about this particular species [here](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/butternut_woollyworm_a_unique_summer_pest_of_walnuts). To narrow down the exact species it would be helpful to edit more information into your post including the types of plants in the area.